# Codeigniter flash message - store the last one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I´m working on flash messages in CodeIgniter. I want to store them in array, but it stores just the last one.

How I want to make it works? For example, I´m saving text into database and I´m saving some images with the text. So I save text -> write flash message, than I´m saving images -> write other flash messages... and than it reloads and I want to write the flash messages array, but it writes just the last one.

My code for flash messages storing:

```
public function set_flash_message($value)
{   
   $admin_flash = $this->session->flashdata('admin_flash');
   $admin_flash[] = $value;
   $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_flash', $admin_flash);
}
```

And here is code for inserting text with 2 flash messages:

```
$this->texts_model->edit_text($id);
$this->upload_files($id, $this->input->post('files_titles'));
$this->set_flash_message('The text was successfully edited!');
$this->set_flash_message('The text was successfully edited! 2'); 
redirect('admin/texts/edit/'.$id);
```

It wrote just "The text was successfully edited! 2";

Thank you for your help!

Comment: where are you doing this work? in library or helper?

Comment: set_flash_message I´m doing in Admin_Controler, by which are extended all controllers used in administration. And the second code I´m doing in texts_admin - controller extende by Admin_Controller

Comment: How are you displaying flashdata finally? imploded with "," or newline?

Comment: like this: http://pastebin.com/ZsAAgahH

Comment: and get_admin_flash_message() is there: http://pastebin.com/nUidmnA8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter doesn't provide any method to get flashdata set in the current call. 'flashdata()' method will only give data set in previous call.

Either use the following line in set_flash_message method

`$admin_flash = $this->session->userdata($this->session->flashdata_key.':new:'.'admin_flash');`
instead of `$admin_flash = $this->session->flashdata('admin_flash');`
or

extend the session library and add a method

```
function get_current_flashdata($key)
{
    $flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':new:'.$key;
    return $this->userdata($flashdata_key);
}
```

Then use `$admin_flash = $this->session->get_current_flashdata('admin_flash');` in set_flash_message method.

Comment: Hm, looks interesting. And if I want to add new message in the second way you described, I will add to $admin_flash what? this?:
$admin_flash .= ':new:'.$value;
$this->session->set_flashdata('admin_flash', $admin_flash);

Or how?

Comment: No just use 'admin_flash'. ':new:' is added internally by codeigniter. i.e., just as you do always `$this->session->set_flashdata('admin_flash', $admin_flash);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$admin_flash[]="";
public function set_flash_message($value)
{     
   $this->session->set_flashdata($admin_flash[], $value);
}
```

In this case you can access them by addressing the index number:

```
echo $this->session->flashdata($admin_flash[0]);
```

Comment: If I used $admin_flash[], it throws me an error "Cannot use [] for reading"